# Using Perl to move commas from end of line to begining of line

Tags: perl, code-formatting

I've inherited a few dozen sql scripts that look like this:

```
select
    column_a,
    column_b,
    column_c
from
    my_table
```

To format them so they match the rest of our sql library, I'd like to change them to look like this:

```
select
    column_a
    ,column_b
    ,column_c
from
    my_table
```

where the commas start at the beginning of the line instead of at the end.  I've taken a few passes at this in Perl, but haven't been able to get it to work just right.

Can any of you Perl gods provide some enlightenment here?

Comment: I would rather correct the rest of the library.

Comment: @Svante: you probably don't like the "perlish" coding style either (http://ysth.info/pcs.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -pi.bak -0777 -wle's/,[^\n\S]*\n([^\n\S]*)/\n$1,/g' file1.sql file2.sql ...
```

The character class is any non-newline whitespace.
-0777 causes it to operate on whole files, not lines.